# How to solve "Class not found" issue in WSO2 ESB REST API deployed from CARs?

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

This is know issue, please refer.
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3246

Currently, I create Sequences and refer this Sequences in outSequence. from my testing, this solved issue when I deployed from CARs. But I don't know, does this is a good way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in ESB 4.9.0 and most probably 4.9.0 will be release within this week.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good workaround. With the next release of the ESB, the problem will be fixed. If you have a support contract with WSO2, you may be able to get a patch for this issue.